# How can a variable be accessed faster via a pointer then straightly?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, assembly

I'm using the next programm to test different simple actions' speed.Here I test speed of loading a variable into a register:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void main()
{
    DWORD _time;

    int val = 1;
    int* ptra = &val;
    for (auto a = 0; a < 20; a++)
    {
        _time = GetTickCount();
        for (auto i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            _asm
            {
                mov         eax, val
            }
        }
        _time = GetTickCount() - _time;
        std::cout << _time << std::endl;
    };
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    for (auto a = 0; a < 20; a++)
    {
        _time = GetTickCount();
        for (auto i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            _asm
            {
                mov     eax, dword ptr[ptra]
                mov     ebx, dword ptr[eax]
            }
        }
        _time = GetTickCount() - _time;
        std::cout << _time << std::endl;
    };
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Average values for tests on my PC are **234** **and** **203**

For some reason, it goes faster via a pointer, then straigthly.I've tested this on two PC's and got the same results.At first i thought that some CP optimization is working, but this would mean, that using pointers is more efficient then variables themselves, sounds awkward.Now I suppose I'm doing something wrong, may be something wrong about GetTickCount(), anyway, I didn't find anything that could help to understand what's going on, neither anyone could explain this.

Results for double pointer are same with straight-access results
The longer the pointer chain, the slower it works

Replacing val with 1 adds some speed, but stil slower then pointer

Empty loops requires same time to finish.Any changes does not affect behaviour.

Here's the code i'm using at the moment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int* ptra;
int val;

void main()
{
    DWORD _time;

    val = 1;
    ptra = &val;

    HANDLE TH = GetCurrentThread();
    HANDLE PH = GetCurrentProcess();
    PDWORD_PTR APMask = new ULONG_PTR;
    PDWORD_PTR ASMask = new ULONG_PTR;
    ULONG_PTR Core = 1;
    GetProcessAffinityMask(PH, APMask, ASMask);
    while (!(Core && *APMask)) Core = Core << 1;
    SetThreadAffinityMask(TH, Core);
    SetThreadPriority(TH, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
    SetPriorityClass(PH, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    DWORD64 ProcessorTime;
#define order 0
#define loops 10000000

    //=========================================
    for (auto a = 0; a < 20; a++)
    {
        //_time = GetTickCount();
        ProcessorTime = __rdtsc();
        for (auto i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            _asm
            {
#if order == 1
                mov     eax, dword ptr[ptra]
                mov     ebx, dword ptr[eax]
#else
                mov         eax, val
#endif
            }
        }
        //_time = GetTickCount() - _time;
        ProcessorTime = __rdtsc() - ProcessorTime;
        std::cout << ProcessorTime << std::endl;
    };
    //system("pause");
    //=========================================
    std::cout << "=" << std::endl;
    //=========================================
    for (auto a = 0; a < 20; a++)
    {
        //_time = GetTickCount();
        ProcessorTime = __rdtsc();
        for (auto i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            _asm
            {
#if order == 1
                mov         eax, val
#else
                mov     eax, dword ptr[ptra]
                mov     ebx, dword ptr[eax]
#endif
            }
        }
        //_time = GetTickCount() - _time;
        ProcessorTime = __rdtsc() - ProcessorTime;
        std::cout << ProcessorTime << std::endl;
    };
    //=========================================
    SetPriorityClass(PH, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    SetThreadPriority(TH, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
    SetThreadAffinityMask(TH, *APMask);
    system("pause");
}
```

Asm code:

```
; 5    : {

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 124                ; 0000007cH
    mov eax, DWORD PTR ___security_cookie
    xor eax, ebp
    mov DWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[ebp], eax
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi

; 6    :    //DWORD _time;
; 7    : 
; 8    :    int* ptra;
; 9    :    int val;
; 10   : 
; 11   :    val = 1;

    mov DWORD PTR _val$[ebp], 1

; 12   :    ptra = &val;

    lea eax, DWORD PTR _val$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR _ptra$[ebp], eax

; 13   :    short unsigned a;
; 14   : 
; 15   :    HANDLE TH = GetCurrentThread();

    call    DWORD PTR __imp__GetCurrentThread@0
    mov DWORD PTR _TH$[ebp], eax

; 16   :    HANDLE PH = GetCurrentProcess();

    call    DWORD PTR __imp__GetCurrentProcess@0
    mov DWORD PTR _PH$[ebp], eax

; 17   :    PDWORD_PTR APMask = new ULONG_PTR;

    push    4
    call    ??2@YAPAXI@Z                ; operator new
    add esp, 4
    mov DWORD PTR $T2[ebp], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR $T2[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR _APMask$[ebp], eax

; 18   :    PDWORD_PTR ASMask = new ULONG_PTR;

    push    4
    call    ??2@YAPAXI@Z                ; operator new
    add esp, 4
    mov DWORD PTR $T1[ebp], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR $T1[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR _ASMask$[ebp], eax

; 19   :    ULONG_PTR Core = 1;

    mov DWORD PTR _Core$[ebp], 1

; 20   :    GetProcessAffinityMask(PH, APMask, ASMask);

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _ASMask$[ebp]
    push    eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _APMask$[ebp]
    push    ecx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _PH$[ebp]
    push    edx
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__GetProcessAffinityMask@12
$LN2@main:

; 21   :    while (!(Core && *APMask)) Core = Core << 1;

    cmp DWORD PTR _Core$[ebp], 0
    je  SHORT $LN16@main
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _APMask$[ebp]
    cmp DWORD PTR [eax], 0
    jne SHORT $LN3@main
$LN16@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _Core$[ebp]
    shl eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _Core$[ebp], eax
    jmp SHORT $LN2@main
$LN3@main:

; 22   :    SetThreadAffinityMask(TH, Core);

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _Core$[ebp]
    push    eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _TH$[ebp]
    push    ecx
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__SetThreadAffinityMask@8

; 23   :    SetThreadPriority(TH, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

    push    15                  ; 0000000fH
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _TH$[ebp]
    push    eax
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__SetThreadPriority@8

; 24   :    SetPriorityClass(PH, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);

    push    256                 ; 00000100H
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _PH$[ebp]
    push    eax
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__SetPriorityClass@8

; 25   :    DWORD64 ProcessorTime;
; 26   : #define order 0
; 27   : #define loops 10000000
; 28   : #define tests 50
; 29   : 
; 30   :    //=========================================
; 31   :    for (a = 0; a < tests; a++)

    xor eax, eax
    mov WORD PTR _a$[ebp], ax
    jmp SHORT $LN6@main
$LN4@main:
    mov ax, WORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    add ax, 1
    mov WORD PTR _a$[ebp], ax
$LN6@main:
    movzx   eax, WORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    cmp eax, 50                 ; 00000032H
    jge SHORT $LN5@main

; 32   :    {
; 33   :        //_time = GetTickCount();
; 34   :        ProcessorTime = __rdtsc();

    rdtsc
    mov DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp], eax
    mov DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp+4], edx

; 35   :        for (auto i = 0; i < loops; i++)

    mov DWORD PTR _i$4[ebp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN9@main
$LN7@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$4[ebp]
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _i$4[ebp], eax
$LN9@main:
    cmp DWORD PTR _i$4[ebp], 10000000       ; 00989680H
    jge SHORT $LN8@main

; 36   :        {
; 37   :            _asm
; 38   :            {
; 39   : #if order == 1
; 40   :                mov     eax, dword ptr[ptra]
; 41   :                mov     ebx, dword ptr[eax]
; 42   : #else
; 43   :                mov         eax, val

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _val$[ebp]

; 44   : #endif
; 45   :            }
; 46   :        }

    jmp SHORT $LN7@main
$LN8@main:

; 47   :        //_time = GetTickCount() - _time;
; 48   :        ProcessorTime = __rdtsc() - ProcessorTime;

    rdtsc
    sub eax, DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp]
    sbb edx, DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp+4]
    mov DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp], eax
    mov DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp+4], edx

; 49   :        std::cout << ProcessorTime << std::endl;

    push    OFFSET ??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@@Z ; std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char> >
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp+4]
    push    eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp]
    push    ecx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@_K@Z
    mov ecx, eax
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@P6AAAV01@AAV01@@Z@Z

; 50   :    };

    jmp SHORT $LN4@main
$LN5@main:

; 51   :    //system("pause");
; 52   :    //=========================================
; 53   :    std::cout << "=" << std::endl;

    push    OFFSET ??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@@Z ; std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char> >
    push    OFFSET ??_C@_01NEMOKFLO@?$DN?$AA@
    mov eax, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
    push    eax
    call    ??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
    add esp, 8
    mov ecx, eax
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@P6AAAV01@AAV01@@Z@Z

; 54   :    //=========================================
; 55   :    for (a = 0; a < tests; a++)

    xor eax, eax
    mov WORD PTR _a$[ebp], ax
    jmp SHORT $LN12@main
$LN10@main:
    mov ax, WORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    add ax, 1
    mov WORD PTR _a$[ebp], ax
$LN12@main:
    movzx   eax, WORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    cmp eax, 50                 ; 00000032H
    jge SHORT $LN11@main

; 56   :    {
; 57   :        //_time = GetTickCount();
; 58   :        ProcessorTime = __rdtsc();

    rdtsc
    mov DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp], eax
    mov DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp+4], edx

; 59   :        for (auto i = 0; i < loops; i++)

    mov DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN15@main
$LN13@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp]
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp], eax
$LN15@main:
    cmp DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp], 10000000       ; 00989680H
    jge SHORT $LN14@main

; 60   :        {
; 61   :            _asm
; 62   :            {
; 63   : #if order == 1
; 64   :                mov         eax, val
; 65   : #else
; 66   :                mov     eax, dword ptr[ptra]

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _ptra$[ebp]

; 67   :                mov     ebx, dword ptr[eax]

    mov ebx, DWORD PTR [eax]

; 68   : #endif
; 69   :            }
; 70   :        }

    jmp SHORT $LN13@main
$LN14@main:

; 71   :        //_time = GetTickCount() - _time;
; 72   :        ProcessorTime = __rdtsc() - ProcessorTime;

    rdtsc
    sub eax, DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp]
    sbb edx, DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp+4]
    mov DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp], eax
    mov DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp+4], edx

; 73   :        std::cout << ProcessorTime << std::endl;

    push    OFFSET ??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@@Z ; std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char> >
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp+4]
    push    eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _ProcessorTime$[ebp]
    push    ecx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@_K@Z
    mov ecx, eax
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@P6AAAV01@AAV01@@Z@Z

; 74   :    };

    jmp SHORT $LN10@main
$LN11@main:

; 75   :    //=========================================
; 76   :    SetPriorityClass(PH, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);

    push    32                  ; 00000020H
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _PH$[ebp]
    push    eax
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__SetPriorityClass@8

; 77   :    SetThreadPriority(TH, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);

    push    0
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _TH$[ebp]
    push    eax
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__SetThreadPriority@8

; 78   :    SetThreadAffinityMask(TH, *APMask);

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _APMask$[ebp]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [eax]
    push    ecx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _TH$[ebp]
    push    edx
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__SetThreadAffinityMask@8

; 79   :    system("pause");

    push    OFFSET ??_C@_05PDJBBECF@pause?$AA@
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__system
    add esp, 4

; 80   : }

    jmp SHORT $LN19@main
    jmp SHORT $LN18@main
$LN19@main:
    xor eax, eax
$LN18@main:
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[ebp]
    xor ecx, ebp
    call    @__security_check_cookie@4
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
```

I get this for MSVC++ 14.0, all optimizations are disbaled (it cuts all aimless code, and so is tested code).

Comment: What is the point to measure unoptimized code?

Comment: How can this be optimized then?

Comment: Naively comparing averages might give you really wrong results. How many measurements did you take? What's the variance? Did you try to take out systematic errors, like does the order in which those two tests are performed matter?

Comment: @DanilК enable optimizations in your compiler.

Comment: By running your instruction in a tight loop you are just measuring how well the CPU can discover that they don't do anything. Your test is unrealistic.

Comment: Note that you're measuring throughput here, not latency. And the throughputs of both are (assuming the code is optimized) probably 1 iteration/cycle, bottlenecked by the loop branch. It's a pretty useless benchmark even with optimized code.

Comment: Try burning some cycles before the first test, so turbo kicks in *before* the benchmark. That doesn't make it a useful benchmark, but it should be more accurate/less surprising.

Comment: You're just measuring which instruction sequence loops faster, and perhaps the first one uses the same core resources the loop uses and the second one doesn't.

Comment: @Slava I've tried a lot of things, all doing the same: tried to let compiler optimize it - as a result first test's speed didn't change, and second one's reached first test's level.Tried to use a const in first test - nothing changed, tried to test unload-from-reg speed - it didn't give anything remarkable.What's for variance - both tests gives same results 3\4 time, value only grows sometimes a bit.

Comment: @harold Each test runs 20 times in a row, i guess 'nough to warm up.Tests uses same cycles, their work time will be same, so their work time can be ignored.Swithcing order of tests changes nothing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz At first I used more realistic tests, but it all was the same; later I discovered that difference is caused by those instructions.

Comment: @harold Well, if troughput speed the same, cycles are same, where does the difference come from?

Comment: @DanilК well maybe they aren't the same, I'm just looking in my crystal ball here since you didn't post the disassembly. There could be a valid reason for them to be different

Comment: there are many possible reasons for this code to vary in performance.  you need to do a lot more work, in particular get the machine code that surrounds the test identical and then mess with alignments (fetch line, cache line) and then you have a fighting chance.  You are doing memory accesses so there will be issues with that, and this is likely running on top of an operating system so there are issues there as well...Oh and this is pipelined and possibly microcoded...Your expectations should be low for accurately measuring these instructions.

Comment: @old_timer I understand it's allmoast unreal to have accurate results, that's why i loop each test so many times and loop each test 20 times.But trend is visible well enough.

Comment: but your loop contains the code doing the measurement, the loop variable the compare, etc.  your alignment is likely not the same so you may be doing more fetches in one loop than the other simply due to alignment.  if one takes three fetches the other four per loop there you go, can even add more instructions so long as you stay within three and still be faster.  then there is caching, and the pipe and the interaction of your test wrapper code and the instructions under test

Comment: looping more times just spreads the first pass issues out, cache misses mostly.  it is fairly trivial to take just the loop code, decrement compare branch if not zero, and make those two/few instrucitons vary in performance by several times, even if written in assembly, number of loops wont change it, you can add nops in the loop and not make it slower or can make it slower depending.  there are too many variables.

Comment: @harold, assembly code is absolutely the same in both cases, just different a's (loop index) and mark's indices.

Comment: you rassumption is correct you are talking about one memory access vs two and the two DOES take longer, but can you measure it?  Is the difference buried in other features?

Comment: Even if all the memory accesses were against the L1 cache, that is still going to be several cycles just for the access to the cache.  So there should be a several cycle difference. Aligning your code to have one need one or two more fetches can also cost you several cycles each fetch.  Again, using only the surounding test code with no instructions under test it is pretty easy to have that code take various amonts of time no matter how many loops you average over.  So then adding instructions under test wont make it better.

Comment: @old_timer, ok, i understood, so can you give an advice about how to correct the alingment?

Comment: @old_timer, at fisrt there was only one cycle, i just got tired of un\commenting required lines.Anyway, i tested loops' speed - same

Comment: @old_timer, noticable difference only appears when loops are not empty.Cycled variables still exist, optimization is disabled

Comment: right, when you change the program and change the alignment the performance changes.  got that.

Comment: @old_timer, well, now i changed programm radically - is not this a reason for performance to change?

Comment: Knowing that the loop overhead code is the same is not enough, it matters what it is specifically, it matters for how it interacts with the other code.

Comment: @harold, you wanna say loop-index processing may interfere with loading a variable?I'll move it to register and check if something changes

Comment: @DanilК can't you just post the disassembly so we can stop taking guesses about what's going on

Comment: @harold, ready.

Comment: Ok good, I don't know the answer though, I've experimented a bit but I'm not making any progress.

Comment: @harold, you were right.I unrolled the loop, placed 20.000 copies of the tested code in a row, and everything became right.I guess this is enough to prove?Don't know what's happening in original code for sure, but that's not that important - nothing like this would take place in reality, that's what David Schwartz was talking about.Thx for help..

Answer (score 0):

You don't work with loop alignment in the code in question, which may produce enough invariance in results to make them meaningless. `$LN13@main:` and `$LN7@main:` has to be aligned in the same way (depends on your platform, how much, actually you should probably align the whole block ahead of `ProcessorTime = __rdtsc();` and probably jump to that address in both cases (after either clearing up caches, or warming them up instead, depends what you want to measure).

That said, on modern x86 both of your codes are on instruction level not even saturating single core, so such `mov` would very likely execute together with other instruction in real world code. All the "time" is eaten by accessing the stack memory and dependencies. For example in second indirect case if you would use only `eax` as destination of both movs, maybe it would slow it down a bit due to bigger clashing.. hmm.. probably not, the CPU has still many spare registers for every new loop iteration, so it will probably avoid any fake dependency/clash by renaming the `eax` every time.

Overall it's meaningless to measure the "scaffolding", you should measure the real algorithm doing something, because the thing you measure will hardly take another +1 cycle more, which will be very likely lost in tens/hundreds cycles of bottleneck of the real code.

Comment: Real code consist of small similar parts, so if i want to write a good code, i should use suitable parts, and I just want to know characteristics of those parts. It's solved allready - difference was caused by the loop; don't know the exact reason, I was probably lucky to hit something specific, that never applies to real code.I replaced loop with repetitive instructions and everything gone the way it was supposed to from the begining.

Comment: @DanilК the alignment of the loop would behave exactly as you described, and would be resolved by unrolling (alignment would hit you only rarely upon looping the whole unrolled block). About writing code... but when you implement some algorithm, you simply have to use those instructions? You don't write additional meaningless ones. Unless you understand programming as "writing instructions", which I'm afraid you do. Anyway, the "small" parts at this scale are useless, because if you write them together, the characteristic of their execution can change tremendously (on modern x86 CPU).

Comment: @DanilК your approach would work somewhere up to 80486, on Pentium (586) your results would be already skewed, and roughly since 786 what you write in ASM source is actually quite far away from what the CPU works with, compiling the x86 instructions into micro operations on the fly, reordering them, etc. (just try your original loop aligned to 256B boundaries (8 is probably enough, but just to be sure) to see if it does "fix" the results too)

Comment: well ,writing algorithm I, normally, have variants of what to write.This programm was born from testing a little algorithm when i got strange results and found the culprit, as I thought.This is the first time I сollided something like this: i mean I know how processors works now, but it's different - to know and to see it live on your screen, espcially when you don't know details, for the fitsr time, that's why I got disoriented.The mistake from the begining was in the size of the tested code combined with inexperience.

Comment: I'd be glad if you tought me how to change code alignment, fast googling didn't reveal anything, so I'll need time to test your suggestion.Though I'll have to study it anyway.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to in C source, I prefer to use standalone assembly files, but try to add `_asm { align 16 }` ahead of `ProcessorTime = __rdtsc();` and verify the resulting assembly has both loops have identical assembly code since there up to the actual `mov` measured, so both labels will have the same alignment (either a good one, or misaligned one, depends how big the instructions ahead of label are). And check symbol table / listing, if the compiler did align them (there will be very likely some no-operation kind of instructions ahead of the `rdtsc`, if it works).

Comment: [Good enough](https://cs541607.userapi.com/c604725/v604725272/2da5a/4_qmLVylvss.jpg), I suppose?This worked, but didn't help.I think some processor optimization is taking place, but works bad due to specificity of the situation.I also tried to add alignment after the tested code, but nothing changed.

Comment: @DanilК does that "npad" really produce `00 00 00 ...` bytes even in real code disassembled? That's not `nop`-like (`add [eax],al`), that would be good for .data segment, but not for .code. In such case it would be better to align it by hand inserting rather n*`nop` instructions. But if it didn't crash, looks like it did align the loop labels correctly, so the timing should have been "fixed" and you just proved I was wrong. Thanks for test and reporting back, I appreciate it.